# MVC - Seeding GUID and table key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, uniqueidentifier

During seeding in MVC how can I prevent GUIDs being generated in the database?

This is my class:

```
[Table("Languages")]
public class Language
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 0)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(SunLite.Models.SunLiteDBContext context)
{
    public static SunLiteDBContext Run(SunLiteDBContext context)
    {
        context.Languages.AddOrUpdate
        (
            x => x.ID,
            new Language { Name = "English", Code = "en-gb", ID = Guid.Parse("{fab5422a-f63d-4042-b7b1-705f69854bc9}"), IsEnabled = true },
            new Language { Name = "Spanish", Code = "es", ID = Guid.Parse("{24380e18-02bf-4668-87ee-b2514d17f384} "), IsEnabled = true },
            new Language { Name = "German", Code = "de", ID = Guid.Parse("{2c05c682-704f-43a4-864b-742ae359aa30}"), IsEnabled = true },
            new Language { Name = "French", Code = "fr", ID = Guid.Parse("{bf929fe3-67a0-425c-81d2-1ef554affc7c} "), IsEnabled = true },
            new Language { Name = "Turkish", Code = "tr", ID = Guid.Parse("{9d09cb45-3d0d-4238-a903-96c4f17481a1} "), IsEnabled = true }
       );
    }
}
```

At the moment this data is added to the database each time with new guids, not the ones I specified.

Comment: Since you are declaring your `ID` property as the `[key]` and of type `Guid`, then this is being generated in the database by calling the `NEWID` function. Take a look at this post: http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to your `ID` property. It should help.

Comment: I'm presuming I will then always have to generate my own GUIDs? What if it's just the seeded ones I want to initialise myself?

Comment: You have two options: always generate guid in code or always generate it in db.